# Accessibility focus does not go to next view on DPAD_RIGHT key from the last item in ScrollView in Andorid

Tags: android, accessibility, focus, scrollview, talkback

[image: UI issue overview]

As mentioned in the image, I have a Scrollview and LinearLayout2 inside a horizontal LinearLayout Parent in TV screen. The problem is that when there are more items and Scroll is required in scrollview, then the accessibility focus of last item does not move to right on DPAD_CENTER key press on remote.

Previous items are moving fine and normal view focus navigation is working fine. When there are few items in scrollview and scroll is not required, then this last item accessibility issue is not happening. Please someone suggest on how to solve this.

Im just using a normal LinearLayout, ScrollView with just width and height params in xml, no other params are used. Also tried to set android:accessibilityTraversalAfter to last item, but does not work.

Comment: You should override performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD/AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD) in your scrollView via setting of accessibilityDelegate or directly in this view.